# Angular 4 throwing Cannot match any routes error with XSS script in URL

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am developing an application in Angular 4. When I am trying to write routes for a feature module, I am getting an error as `Error: Cannot match any routes.`

Here's the routes code I have used:

```
const COURSE_ROUTES: Routes = [
  {path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full'},
  {path: ':name', component: CourseComponent},
  {path: '**', component: ErrorComponent}
];
```

Routing is working fine and going to the `CourseComponent` when the route is something like `course/angular` or `course/some-course-name` but when I try to inject some XSS script into the same route, such as

`course/<script>alert('0wn3d')</script>`,

its throwing an error as

`ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''0wn3d'' Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: ''0wn3d'`

though I have written a wild card entry for error routes. I have tested that the

```
{path: '**', component: ErrorComponent}
```

is showing the 404 error page, by removing the

```
{path: ':name', component: CourseComponent}
```

and running the app with some random url like `course/some-course`

Please help me resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to have `/` as the root URL.

```
  {path: 'some-name:name',pathMatch: 'full',component:CourseComponent}
```

[Documented here](https://angular.io/guide/router)

[image]

Comment: I am in a feature module, not in the app root module. The path currently I am working on is `localhost:4200/course/course-name`, not `localhost:4200/course-name`

Comment: are you using lazy loading?

Comment: Yes, I am using with lazy loading with preloading strategy.